# how to add and retrieve data from plist programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, plist

hello all
       I am new to objective c and i want to insert data dynamically/programmatically into plist.please help me.Here is my plist structure

```
root
  |_Client1
        |_report1
             |_application1
             |_application2

        |_report2
             |_application3

  |_Client2
       |_report1
```

Now i want to add and retrieve data dynamically to application1,application2 in my plist 
please help me

Comment: Use the [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html) instead.

Comment: You can read from a plist to a dictionary with [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:) and write it out using [[myDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984722/how-to-write-nsmutabledictionary-into-plist)

Answer (score 11):

**Reading content of .plist file ..**

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"league" ofType:@"plist"];
contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

**Writing to .plist file.**

```
NSMutableDictionary * myDictionary;
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"league" ofType:@"plist"];
[myDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

**Note that:** 
Dictionary must contain plist objects (instances of `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`). And dictionary keys must be `NSString` objects

Comment: change "path" to "plistPath".