# how to edit a plist programmatically in xcode 5 iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist, xcode5.1

how can I edit or change a value string from:

[image]

in this plist I need change or Set "NO" in Enabled Value from Item 2, I see a lot examples, but not working, or are deprecated, or don't use ARC, any idea or example code? please help guys

EDIT#1: I try this (not work)

```
 NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"List.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:CONTENT_DEFAULT ofType:PLIST];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:path error:nil];
    }

    NSArray*  newContent = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *Dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[newContent objectAtIndex:2]];
     [Dict setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"Enabled"];
      [Dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

NOTE: not work, it crashes send me:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x15de7ff0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Enabled.', or Im wrong in something?
```

EDIT #2  new Try

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSString *savingPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

    NSArray*  newContent = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableDictionary *Dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[newContent objectAtIndex:2]];
    [Dict setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"Enabled"];
    savingPath = [savingPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Modified.plist"];
    [Dict writeToFile:savingPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"newContent:%@",newContent);
    NSArray *newnew = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:savingPath];
    NSLog(@"newnew:%@",newnew);
```

NOTE: now print me a crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (2)'
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You won't see the change in the Xcode built in editor. BTW, it should be `[newContent objectAtIndex:3]`, not 2.

Comment: thanks Sergius, I did edit the question about the crash

Comment: The variable *dict should be `NSMutableDictionary`. And try `NSLogging` it - update us with the output.

Comment: thanks Sergius, now not crash but not change anything in my plist

Comment: I NSLogging but print me (null) maybe is the path but how can I fix this?

Comment: The first try does not work because the type of the list is "Array", not "Dictionary".

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of a regular dictionary to modify stuff. You have to always check that the object you are editing is there.

To get the right path for the plist you created in `Xcode` you need to use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];
```

You might actually want to save that file into the app's document directory. So you would use the following path for saving the content:

```
NSString *savingPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
savingPath = [savingPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Modified.plist"];
[Dict writeToFile:savingPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Sergius,I need create a new plist with "Modified.plist" name? or this save in the same "List.plist", because, I did try both and not save or edited the plist

Comment: @user_Dennis_Mostajo that's strange. You have to `NSLog` the given plist, see that it is there, then edit it and save it to a new file. You **can't** save the plist to app's bundle, you **won't** see it in Xcode! Check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674011/how-to-add-and-retrieve-data-from-plist-programmatically

Comment: I try to save in a new plist but now print me a crash log :*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (4)'

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case the solution would be the following (when you have Dictionary as a member of Array):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *newContent = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
//iterating through all members since all of them has the string "YES" which should be replaced, otherwise, you will need to create a separate dictionary for each member
for ((i = 0; i < [newContent count]; i++)){
//here you take the member (dictionary) of the array
    NSDictionary *dictOfArray = [newContent objectAtIndex:i];
    [dictOfArray objectForKey:@"Enabled"]=@"NO";
    }
//if you update the same pList you can use the same path (otherwise use another path)
[newContent writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

So, it works now.