# Creating a property list file programmatically in the main bundle of cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - Writing NSMutableDictionary to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361630/iphone-writing-nsmutabledictionary-to-file)

How to create a property list file programmatically inside the MainBundle of cocoa application. I know to how to read and write the contents to the plist file.

Comment: You cannot modify contents in the MainBundle.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984722/how-to-write-nsmutabledictionary-into-plist, triplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361630/iphone-writing-nsmutabledictionary-to-file

Comment: this isn't a duplicate, all other comparisons are iOS, the OP wanted to know about Cocoa.  While similar, they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

I write arrays to a plist and read it out using code similar to the below. May be useful.

```
- (NSString *)offlineCachePath {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cache = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [cache stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfApp"];

    // Check if the path exists, otherwise create it
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    return path;
}

- (NSString *)cachedStuffPath {
    NSString *cachedStuffPath = [[self offlineCachePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfFile.plist"];
    return cachedStuffPath;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getCachedStuff {
    return [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self cachedStuffPath]] mutableCopy];
}

- (void)cacheStuff:(NSMutableArray *)stuff {
    [stuff writeToFile:[self cachedStuffPath] atomically:YES];
}
```